# How to adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to UIButton label ? ios

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, uiedgeinsets

when i set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to the button UILabel, the text go out side of the button frame, I don't know why ?

here is my code:

```
            shareBtn = UIButton()

            shareBtn.setTitle(IconsConstants.share, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            shareBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.iconmoonFont(100)
            shareBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
            shareBtn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
            shareBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center


            //EdgeInsets

            shareBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: remove the inset, set an allowed font scale

Comment: what changed? is the text resizing? what is your intention with the inset?

Comment: @Wain , the share icon still go outside the button frame !  , I am using inset to set padding for the icon. please note that the white border is a button layer which describe the button frame border

Answer (score 0):

for single line set

```
shareBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

instead of this

```
factLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

for multiple line us use

```
actLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
factLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(factLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize expectSize = [factLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
factLabel.frame = CGRectMake(factLabel.frame.origin.x, factLabel.frame.origin.y, expectSize.width, expectSize.height);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , do you mean that i should use UILable instead of UIButton ?